# How to Get FedEx Zone code if I know the origin and destination Zip Codes?

Tags: php, fedex

Can any one tell me how can i get zones from origin and destination zip code from php code like we can get zone from this http://www.fedex.com/ratetools/RateToolsMain.do?method=SetupFindZones

Answer (score 3):

```
$orig_zip = '32819';
$dest_zip = '90210';

$request = 'http://www.fedex.com/ratetools/RateToolsMain.do?method=FindZones&origPostalCd=' 
    . $orig_zip . '&destCountryCd=us&destPostalCd=' . $dest_zip;

$data = file_get_contents($request);

preg_match_all('/>(\d+) </', $data, $match);

print_r($match[1]);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8 // Express Zone
    [1] => 8 // Ground Zone
)
```

However, you should still use an API to retrieve this information. Apparently they offer the download of their zone data, so you should be able to just insert it into your DB to lookup directly. See: ftp://ftp.fedex.com/pub/us/rates/downloads/documents2/92600-92899.pdf

Comment: Thanks :) i think it will work...I will implement this and will let you know.

Comment: Really can't believe they don't have a data dump which is import-friendly. Even the text or csv files are in non-standard formats spread across ~700 separate files.   
For that reason, the "you should still use an API to retrieve this information" line just isn't a practical feasibility.  
The rest of your answer is a goldmine.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I am running into the same problem....7 years later

Answer (score -1):

FedEx provides a web service to for pricing and other information.
Have a look at their pages about [web services](http://www.fedex.com/us/web-services/index.html) and the [FedEx Developer Resource Center](http://www.fedex.com/us/developer/index.html).

Comment: Yea, neither one of those resources answers the question. Even after digging into the API, there is no way to get the zone difference from two zip codes.